# Как реализовать отправку запроса используя протокол SIP

Tags: tcp, sip

Прочитал статью на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/189332/, но не могу понять как реализовать отправку запроса, используя TCP? Весь запрос слать одним пакетом или как?

Comment: tcp используется, чтобы разрезать и доставить поток данных удаленному узлу. вы вообще не должны думать про пакеты tcp, посылая через него данные, у вас есть поток байтов, который вы скармливаете tcp-подключению. Разрежется лиэто в tcp на пакеты - дело MTU, он имеет право хоть по пакету на байт создать, разницы никакой.

Comment: @etki Оформите в виде ответа